# fixing mySQL replication (large DB)

Tags: mysql, replication, mysqldump

I have a large mySQL database and I am replicating to two slaves.  All three servers are windows (i know).  One of my slaves seems to have corruption, the other is fine.  This is huge DB, a few hundred gigs.  I am trying to figure out the best way to fix the replication on the one slave that is corrupted.  I need to minimize downtime to the master so a mySQLdump seems problematic unless its the only way.  I was wondering if because I have two slaves and I am pretty sure all 3 environments are close to identical there might be another creative way to solve this.  It is InnoDB but might I be able to shut all three down and do a directory copy of the good slave (datadir) and use it on the bad slave, restart?  I think that might only take a few hours as opposed to a mySQLdump.  Any thoughts on how to accomplish this correctly would be helpful.

Comment: run pt-table-checksum on the master, it will show your inconsistencies between the master and all slaves.
If there are any you can fix them with pt-table-sync

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a functioning Slave, you can rebuild the bad Slave in two different methods

For these examples

- MAS : Master:
- SL1 : Slave (Good one)
- SL2 : Slave (Bad one)

## METHOD #1

This method requires that you stop using the good Slave for the duration of the recovery

- STEP 01 : On SL2, Run `STOP SLAVE;`
- STEP 02 : On SL1, Run `STOP SLAVE;`
- STEP 03 : On SL1, Run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`
- STEP 04 : Record `Read_Master_Log_File` and `Exec_Master_Log_Pos` From `STEP 03`
- STEP 05 : mysqldump data from SL1 to a SQL text file
- STEP 06 : Load mysqldump into SL2
- STEP 07 : ON SL2, `CHANGE MASTER TO master_log_file='(Read_Master_Log_File From STEP 03)',master_log_pos=(Exec_Master_Log_Pos From STEP 03)`
- STEP 08 : On SL2, Run `START SLAVE;`
- STEP 09 : On SL2, Run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` and Look at `Seconds_Behind_Master`
- STEP 10 : Repeat STEP 09 until `Seconds_Behind_Master` is 0

After this, you can use SL1 and SL2 for reads

## METHOD #2

This method requires that you shutdown mysqld on SL1 and SL2

- STEP 01 : On SL1, Run `STOP SLAVE;`
- STEP 02 : On SL2, Run `STOP SLAVE;`
- STEP 03 : On SL1, Run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`
- STEP 04 : On SL1, Run `net stop mysql`
- STEP 05 : On SL2, Run `net stop mysql`
- STEP 06 : Copy entire datadir of SL1 over to SL2. Make sure you copy `master.info` file because it contains replication coordinates needed of SL2 to continue replication on startup. Make sure you copied the relay logs as well.
- STEP 07 : On SL1, Run `net start mysql`
- STEP 08 : On SL2, Run `net start mysql`

## CAVEAT

If every table is InnoDB, MAS does not need to be shutdown at all. SL1 just needs a stable place to stop replication before copying to SL2.

## Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2014-03-14 15:51 EDT

If you are planning to use the Master (since you are moving the Master to another Data Center), here is some advice.

- STEP 01 : Stop application writes to MAS
- STEP 02 : On MAS, run `RESET MASTER;` (Deletes all binary logs)
- STEP 03 : On MAS, `net stop mysql`
- STEP 04 : Copy the MAS server's datadir to the Slave's datadir
- STEP 05 : On the new MAS, `net start mysql` (DO not have any application write to MAS yet)
- STEP 06 : ON the New MAS, `SHOW MASTER STATUS;`
- STEP 07 : On the Slave, `net start mysql`
- STEP 08 : On the Slave, run `CHANGE MASTER TO master_log_file='binlog from STEP 06',master_log_pos=(Position from STEP 06);`
- STEP 09 : On the Slave, run `START SLAVE;`
- STEP 10 : Start application writes to MAS

No need to copy binlogs doing it like this. All a Slave cares about is the latest binlog.

Comment: thanks you! method 2 seems close to what i was thinking.  I assume in step 7 and 8 you mean net start mysql

Comment: I changed `net stop` to `net start`. Thanks !!!

Comment: i assume i could do the same basic thing if i were moving a master from one server to a new server as long as it was windows to windows and same mysql version?  copy the entire datadir without an issue?  Anything with bin logs I would have to do special in this case? (i ask because we are thinking of moving our hosting to a new datacenter as well.

Comment: I updated my answer with a third method

Comment: much appreciated friend.